# Blender glitches and a cube show up inside the cube model and shows no materials plus it doesn't render anything

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Blender doesn't show materials and it has a model inside model effect thingy. Solid view works fine materials view doesn't show materials and rendered view shows this glitch effect thing (in EEVEE, in Cycles rendered view works fine but in materials view the cube is again blank).

Today i installed 2.91 and it still occurs. Any ideas on how to fix it?
Screenshot in rendered view:
[image: Screenshot in rendered view:]

Screenshot of when i scroll to zoom:
[image: Screenshot of when i scroll to zoom:]

Screenshot when i rotate view:
[image: Screenshot when i rotate view:]

Also screenshot of render in Eevee:
[image: render screen]

Comment: The only time I remember seeing this happen is when I pause rendering in cycles, do you have any principled bsdf plugged into the material?